# ClassNotFoundException Unity android plugin

Tags: android, class, unity-game-engine, exception, plugins

I'm having trouble with a plugin I created to use in Unity.
The plugin script was created in Android Studio and I imported the .arr built file into Assets/plugin/android
There are no build, console errors but I have this error in logcat when the method is called:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I'm addressing it correctly and added its activity in my manifest. Here's my script:

```
unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
unityActivity = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
fileManager = new AndroidJavaObject("com.greentactic.filechooser.MainClass", 
unityActivity);

object[] parameters = new object[2];
parameters[0] = unityActivity;
parameters[1] = "Opening File Manager";

fileManager.Call("PrintString", parameters);
fileManager.Call("StartSearch");
```

And here's my plugin script:

```
public class MainClass extends AppCompatActivity{

private static final int RESULT_CODE = 43;

public void PrintString(final Context ctx, final String message )
{
  //create / show an android toast, with message and short duration.
  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public void StartSearch(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent , RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent 
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(data != null){
            String path = data.getData().getPath();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access android native file picker from Unity.